Ternary and union types
I'm working with TypeScript 5, and I'm having trouble with type narrowing when using a boolean flag to determine the shape of an object. I expected TypeScript to be able to correctly infer the types, but I'm getting a type error.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
type Input = {
  isMulti: true,
  value: string[]
} | {
  isMulti: false,
  value: string
}

function multi({ isMulti, value }: Input) {
  if (isMulti) {
    return value[0];
  }
  return value;
}

function test(incomingMulti: boolean) {
  const value = incomingMulti ? ['1'] : '1';
  return multi({ isMulti: incomingMulti, value });
}

Playground
I'm getting the following error on the line where I call the multi function:
Argument of type '{ isMulti: boolean; value: string | string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Input'.
  Type '{ isMulti: boolean; value: string | string[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ isMulti: false; value: string; }'.
    Types of property 'isMulti' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.

I assumed that TypeScript would be able to infer the correct type based on the value of isMulti:

if true: value is string[]
if false: value is string
if boolean: value is string | string[]

However, it seems to be arbitrarily choosing the false path.
Interestingly, this works:
function test2(incomingMulti: boolean) {
  if (incomingMulti) {
    multi({ isMulti: true, value: ['1'] });
  } else
    multi({ isMulti: false, value: '1' });
}

but I don't want to force the developers to write it like that every time.

"it seems to be arbitrarily choosing the false path" - when it fails to find a match in a union, it shows the last one. If you switch the cases around you get Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.(2345) instead: https://tsplay.dev/WJkjZw. Fundamentally the problem is what the error tells you, you're trying to pass { isMulti: boolean, value: string[] | string }, which is not either component of Input.

This is an instance of ms/TS#30581; TS doesn't understand correlated unions, nor can it distribute code flow analysis over union types (as I suggested in the declined ms/TS#25051). Normally the refactoring for this is to use generics but here it's much more annoying to do that than to just assert as Input. Like, this is close, and even that uses strings instead of booleans. Yuck. Does that fully address the question? if so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks for the comments!
@jcalz, fantastic explanation! Although I can't convince other developers to use the Map solution in my current scenario, it's the best solution out there, as far as I know. I'll gladly accept your answer so others may use it to get to the root cause of the problem until Typescript deals with this issue differently. And double thank you for advocating for a solution in the TS repo.

TypeScript doesn't follow correlations among union types. Conceptually, {isMulti: incomingMulti: value} would be of type {isMulti: true, value: string[]} if incomingMulti is truthy, and of type {isMulti: false, value: string} if not. But TypeScript doesn't analyze that object literal twice. It does it all at once, and so the type is {isMulti: boolean, value: string | string[]}, which is not assignable to Input (since you could write {isMulti: true, value: "oops"}).  The correlation between incomingMulti and value has been lost.
This is the basic problem described in microsoft/TypeScript#30581.  It would be nice if you could tell TypeScript to analyze the body of test twice, once for each possible narrowing of incomingMulti, as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#25051. But that feature request was declined.
By far the easiest way to proceed is to use a type assertion to just tell the compiler that your value is a valid Input:
function test(incomingMulti: boolean) {
  const value: string | string[] = incomingMulti ? ['1'] : '1';
  multi({ isMulti: incomingMulti, value } as Input);
}

Or you could write redundant code, the way test2 is written.
Or, if you were really serious about trying to get TypeScript to follow such correlations, you'd need to do a sizable refactoring as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. But I wouldn't recommend it here; that refactoring involves making everything generic, and the underlying union type needs to have the discriminant be a keylike type such as a string and not a boolean.  That refactoring looks like
interface InputMap {
  true: string[],
  false: string
}

type Input<K extends keyof InputMap = keyof InputMap> =
  { [P in K]: { isMulti: P, value: InputMap[P] } }[K]

function multi<K extends keyof InputMap>({ isMulti, value }: Input<K>): string {
  const f: { [K in keyof InputMap]: (x: InputMap[K]) => string } = {
    true: v => v[0],
    false: v => v
  }
  return f[isMulti](value)
}

function test<K extends keyof InputMap>(incomingMulti: K) {
  const value: InputMap[K] = { true: ['1'], false: '1' }[incomingMulti];
  const input: Input<K> = { isMulti: incomingMulti, value };
  multi(input);
}

And, while it works and isn't redundant (in the sense that you are calling multi(input) just once), it's fairly far from what you originally wrote (and requires "true" and "false" instead of true and false), and is complicated.
If I were you and I wanted to keep this pattern I'd just use a type assertion.
Playground link to code
